# Nested xhr call doesn't work with Android

Tags: android, titanium, xmlhttprequest, appcelerator

I have a code that works great on iPhone, but when it comes to make it run on Android, it ignores some parts.
The problem is that I have nested `createHTTPClient` calls:

```
var xhr1 = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr1.open('GET',url1);
xhr1.send();
xhr1.onload = function(e) {
  var list1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
  var list1Length = list1.length;
  Titanium.API.info('list1 length : ' + list1Length);
  var fctForList2 = function(argument){
    var xhr2 = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr2.open('GET',url1);
    xhr2.send();
    xhr2.onload = function(e) {
      // display list where a value corresponds to the argument
      var list2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var list2Length = list2.length;
      Titanium.API.info('list2 length : ' + list2Length);
    };
  };

  var argument = list1[0].someValue;
  fctForList2(argument);
};
```

So in the code above, I found a workaround that runs great on iPhone.
As you know, the synchronous mode can't be forced (even if the documentation mentions that it can be done) so I have used this method to call the second `xhr` synchronously.

But why the `list2Length` is `null` with Android?

PS: I work under OSX with the Titanium SDK 1.6. For my tests on Android, I use the emulator (API 2.2) and a device (2.1update1).

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would do it like that:

```
var xhr1 = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var xhr2 = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr2.onload = function(e) {
      // display list where a value corresponds to the argument
      var list2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var list2Length = list2.length;
      Titanium.API.info('list2 length : ' + list2Length);
};

xhr1.onload = function(e) {
     var list1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
     var list1Length = list1.length;
     Titanium.API.info('list1 length : ' + list1Length);

     //second request
     xhr2.open('GET',url1);
     xhr2.send();
};

xhr1.open('GET',url1);
xhr1.send();
```

for what is the "argument"?

you need to declare the onload function before calling the .open and .send method.

Comment: this is not recommended.. it will work, but you probably only want one httpClient created at a time.